# Remove invalid and incorrect spatial points (Latitude and longitude) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse, latitude-longitude

I have well over 100,000 GPS locations of 35 animals. I have removed the 'NA' and '0' GPS latitude-longitude locations but noticed that there was one latitude and longitude location that was incorrect and that needs to be removed (in this subset of data, the 4th line that has -78.6917357    17.5506138 as LAT and LON). It is likely that there are other incorrect GPS locations and wondered if there is an easy way to identify outliers and remove them.

My sample data looks like this:

```
COLLAR  NAME    Animal_ID   SEX DATE    TIME    Year    Month   Day Hour    LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   HEIGHT
26  Keith   CM8 M   2009-05-28  2:00:00 2009    5   28  2   49.7518424  -123.6099396    705.87
26  Keith   CM8 M   2009-06-09  7:00:00 2009    6   9   7   49.7518495  -123.4860212    191.61
26  Keith   CM8 M   2009-05-31  18:00:002009    5   31  18  49.7518576  -123.5373316    410.96
26  Jack    CM6 M   2009-06-01  22:00:002009    6   1   22  -78.6917357  17.5506138 490.23
26  Keith   CM8 M   2009-05-28  2:00:00 2009    5   28  2   49.7518424  -123.6099396    705.87
26  Keith   CM8 M   2009-06-09  7:00:00 2009    6   9   7   49.7518495  -123.4860212    191.61
26  Keith   CM8 M   2009-05-31  18:00:002009    5   31  18  49.7518576  -123.5373316    410.96
27  Keith   CM8 M   2009-05-28  3:00:00 2009    5   28  3   49.7518775  -123.6099242    713.05
27  Keith   CM8 M   2009-06-09  10:00:002009    6   9   10  49.7519163  -123.486203  108.02
```

The code I used is this which works to remove the 0 and NA:

```
    library(dplyr)
    data <- data_all %>%
     filter(!is.na(LATITUDE), LATITUDE !=0,!is.na(LONGITUDE), LONGITUDE !=0)
```

Now, I would like to further remove row 4 here (and any other invalid or incorrect spatial points) using the following line of code but that does not work:

```
data <- filter(LATITUDE !=-78.69174, LONGITUDE !=17.55061)
```

I cannot see a reduction in the number of rows after running this code. Please note that I do not have row numbers so cannot specifically remove row 4 and, ideally, I want to remove all those rows that have odd values in one line of code (or as a pipe function) that does work. Your help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1) your filter line doesn't start from a data frame so will return an error. 2) Matching against a many-digit floating point number is a recipe for surprises, since there are likely more underlying digits. Compare `data.frame(my_num = c(pi, sqrt(2))) %>% filter(my_num %>% near(3.141593, tol = 0.0001))` to `data.frame(my_num = c(pi, sqrt(2))) %>% filter(my_num == 3.141593)`. 3) If there are other outliers it might be simpler to whitelist desired ranges of values, eg `LATITUDE < -120` instead of excluding specific lines.

Comment: @JonSpring thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I am a very basic R user so do not really understand the code you have provided. Would you please be able to write that using my "data" which was read into R from a .csv file to convert that to a dataframe if that is what you are suggesting in Pt 1. Thank you!

Comment: Can you define for us what kinds of conditions would indicate "odd values"? Should all the locations be near Vancouver?

Answer (score 0):

The stored values are likely different than what is displayed. Use dplyr::near for approximate matches to coordinates you know are incorrect.  If I were you, id use mutate first to flag incorrect coordinates via a new boolean column, then filter on that boolean column

Comment: Thanks @Ralph Asher, I am a very basic R user and do not know what you mean by using the dplyr::near or the mutate function in this case to flag incorrect coordinates. Are you able to please provide me with the line of code to do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that limits to values of latitude and longitude within an expected range:

```
data <- data_all %>%
     filter(!is.na(LATITUDE),  between(LATITUDE,  49, 51),
            !is.na(LONGITUDE), between(LONGITUDE, -125, -122))
```

or equivalently

```
data <- data_all %>%
         filter(!is.na(LATITUDE),  LATITUDE  >= 49,   LATITUDE  <= 51,
                !is.na(LONGITUDE), LONGITUDE >= -125, LONGITUDE <= -122)
```

Comment: thank you, that definitely did reduce the number of rows, however, 3529 were rows were removed. So maybe I need to increase the lat and lon values? You seem to be familiar with the area, but these values are in the South Coast region of BC just outside of Vancouver. The reason I think there is only one odd value is because I 'sorted' the data by Latitude and saw that one odd value. Hence, I feel that is the only odd value that should be removed. However, as mentioned above, with your r code 3529 rows were removed. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks for your help.

Comment: You are in a better position to know which coordinates you want to include. If you poke around in google maps you can get the coordinates for spots in the area you care about. You could also just expand to eg latitude 45 to 55.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got the solution: 
test <- read.csv(file.choose())

head(test)
summary(test)

plot(test$LONGITUDE, test$LATITUDE)

test2 <- test %>% 
  dplyr::filter(LATITUDE > 0)  and that worked.